# Azure startup task Appcmd to config my site

Tags: iis, azure, startup, appcmd

I have a azure site running, and I want to solve the notorious application pool restart warm up issue. It seems that MS has release for Application Initialization IIS.

So I have to do the following 
1. Install Application Initialization
2. Make some configuration changes mentioned in here http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1089/iis-80-application-initialization/

a) In Application pool section of %WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config file

b) In site section of %WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config file
 
    ...
    
    ....

My question is, how to write the Appcmd script to solve 2. b) to add **preloadEnabled="true"** to the right place, because i need to do 1) find the root site, given that I dont know the sitename, nor the site id. 2) add the **preloadEnabled="true"**  property to the root site I found in step 2).

Answer (score 1):

Coupled with David's answer to reset the idle timeout, you can also prevent the app pools from recycling at all by using the following as a startup task:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.recycling.periodicRestart.time:00:00:00
```

You also need to set two other things: `startMode` and `preloadEnabled`.

For `startMode`, you can add this to the startup task you created for the code above:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.startMode:AlwaysRunning
```

For `preloadEnabled`, you can do what Alex said and do this in your startup task:

```
appcmd set app "websitename/vdirname" /preloadEnabled:true
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as avoiding restart, add this command to your startup script:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.processModel.idleTimeout:00:00:00
```

Not sure about your preload question.

Comment: This only solves the application pool goes to sleep every 20 min problem. However, What I am trying to solve here is the problem that Application pool recycles every 1740 min. This application initialization module (http://forums.iis.net/t/1176740.aspx) of iis is supposedly solving that problem by hitting the site every time app pool recycle finish. But I need to make some configurations upon startup of IIS

Answer (score 0):

There's a sample on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2011/02/18/installing-and-using-an-httpmodule-in-windows-azure.aspx. Essentially, you need to set executionContext to elevated, so your web role's entry point (but not ASP.NET application) will run under administrator previlige. Inside the entry point, you can use IIS administration API to configure the warm up module.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to configure the site/application pool using an AppCmd startup task, check out my recent post about this:

http://mvolo.com/configure-iis-websites-windows-azure-startup-tasks-appcmd/

This covers how to find the site/application pool to edit, and also how to run the task AFTER the site/apppool configuration is created and not before.

We are actually enabling application warmup via serviceAutoStartProviders using this approach, I will blog about the configuration tool we use / issues we solved in a later post.

If you need help with that now, send me an email.

Comment: I have a question currently with a large bounty using your solution, that you might be able to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086107/mutual-2-way-ssl-between-azure-cloud-service-and-salesforce

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but to hopefully answer this part :

> how to write the Appcmd script to solve 2. b) to add preloadEnabled="true" to the right place, because i need to do

Use the `appcmd` :

```
appcmd set app "websitename/vdirname" /preloadEnabled:true
```

Regards Alex

Comment: if you dont have any V dir using "websitename/" will work just fine