# Mutual (2-way) SSL between Azure Cloud Service and Salesforce

Tags: azure, ssl, salesforce, ssl-certificate

### Overview

So I've been jumping through flaming hoops to trying to create a Mutual (2-way) SSL connection between a WCF service hosted on a cloud service (using a webrole) and a Salesforce callout.  I'm creating a mega question to outline all the steps I've taken and where I am currently stuck.

### Process/Progress

**1: Set up SSL on Azure Cloud Service (Success)**

- Created **CNAME** pointing the SSL domain *(service.mydomain.com)* to azure production endpoint *(service.cloudapp.net)*
- Uploaded a signed Certificate to Azure
- Added Certificate to WebRole and configured a Https Endpoint using certificate
- Created WCF web.config binding with Security Mode="Transport"

After doing this 1-way SSL is working correctly

**2: Create Client Certificate using with salesforce. This is an unsigned certificate issued by salesforce.  You can download it as a .cer (DONE)**

**3: Install Salesforce Client Certificate using a Start-up Task ([see this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/05/27/how-to-add-certificate-in-your-azure-vm-using-startup-task.aspx)) (DONE, but I'm not sure how to confirm it really worked other than the fact that no error was thrown on deployment)**

**4: Set up WCF to require Client Certificate (DONE, see web.config)**

**5: Unlock VM IIS webserver/security/access/sslflags using Startup task in WebRole and 
Override setting in WCF web.config (DONE, see startup.cmd and web.config)**

Apparently with Cloud services the Startup tasks will run before IIS is actually configured on the VM. Because of this I had to implement a hack using ping to delay and running in the background.  This actually seems to work as before I was getting a **500 - Configuration Error**.

**6: Send Client Certificate in SF Request (DONE, see SF code)**

**Result:**
I get a 403.7 - Forbidden error from the server.  I believe that it has something to do with the SF Certificate not being trusted by the Service but I can be sure.  It's obviously next to impossible to test because of the Cloud to Cloud nature of the system.

## UPDATE

So I was able to resolve the 403.7 error by changing the store from 'root' to 'ca'.  However now I'm dealing with an inconsistency issue where sometimes the start.cmd seems to work and other times it doesn't seem to take any or only partial effect.  If my reboot my service it cycles between 500 errors for the configuration flags being locked by IIS, the 403.7 error mentioned above, and it actually working perfectly.

I found this [blog post](http://mvolo.com/configure-iis-websites-windows-azure-startup-tasks-appcmd/) that uses a custom program (ExecWithRetries.exe) to delay and retry startup tasks until they complete successfully, but I'm still not getting inconsistent results (maybe because appcmd might not throw an error even if it runs before IIS is configured by the VM?).

What my **startup.cmd** now looks like:

```
%windir%\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe unlock config /section:system.webServer/security/access
REM certutil -addstore -enterprise -f -v root Startup\MagnetClient.cer
certutil -addstore ca Startup\MagnetClient.cer
```

And the task config like this:

```
<startup>
   <Task commandLine="Startup/ExecWithRetries.exe &quot;/c:AddCert.cmd&quot; /d:60000 /r:20 /rd:5000" executionContext="elevated" taskType="background" />
</startup>
```

If anyone can has a solution to get consistent result I will award them the bounty.

## Code References

**WCF web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFServiceWebRole1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="metadata" >
        <endpoint name="basicHttp"  
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="https" 
                  contract="WCFServiceWebRole1.IService1" >

        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="https">
          <!-- Step 1 -->
          <security mode="Transport">
            <!-- step 4 -->
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="metadata">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"  />
          <!--<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>-->
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>

    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/>
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true" />

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!-- Override iis config mentioned in step 5 -->
    <security>
      <access sslFlags="SslRequireCert"/>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**WebRole Service Definitions**

```
<ServiceDefinition name="WindowsAzureProject1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2013-03.2.0">
  <WebRole name="WCFServiceWebRole1">
    <!-- step 3 & 5 -->
    <Startup>
      <Task commandLine="Startup/startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="background">
      </Task>
    </Startup>
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
          <Binding name="Endpoint2" endpointName="Endpoint2" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
      <!-- step 1 -->
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint2" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="example.example.com" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
    </Imports>
    <LocalResources>
      <LocalStorage name="WCFServiceWebRole1.svclog" sizeInMB="1000" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" />
    </LocalResources>
    <Certificates>
      <!-- Step 1 -->
      <Certificate name="example.example.com" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
      <Certificate name="Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Trust" />
      <Certificate name="Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Trust" />
    </Certificates>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

**startup.cmd**

```
REM *HACK to wait a ridiculously long time until we can be
REM *pretty sure the VM has initialized IIS
ping -n 600 127.0.0.1 nul
%windir%\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe unlock config /section:system.webServer/security/access
REM add SF client certy to root store
certutil -addstore -enterprise -f -v root Statup\ClientCert.cer
```

**Sales Force Example Code**

```
string b = '';
b = b + '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body>';
b = b + '<TestService xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">';
b = b + '<echoString>test Message</echoString>';
b = b + '</TestService></s:Body></s:Envelope>';

Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
//this should add the certificate created by salesforce
req.setClientCertificateName('MyClientCert');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setEndpoint('https://service.mydomain.com/service1.svc');
req.setHeader('Content-type','text/xml');
req.setHeader('SoapAction', 'http://tempuri.org/IService1/TestService');
req.setBody( b );
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
string m = res.getbody();

System.Debug(m);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer a couple suggestions:

1. [Enable RemoteAccess](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/remote-desktop/) to your azure deployment and redeploy.  Then login and MMC to the Cert store to see if the SalesForce client cert actually got installed.
2. Add `<Runtime executionContext="elevated" />` right after `<WebRole name="WCFServiceWebRole1">` in your service configuration (see my answer to this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448689/azure-autoscaling-works-locally-but-not-when-deployed/14468164#14468164)) to ensure the worker process has access to the cert store.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: A reliable way to delay is to use the CHOICE command:

```
:: Delay for 60 seconds

%windir%\System32\choice.exe /D Y /T 60 > NUL:
```

To capture the output of commands redirect the error and standard output to a file you can get to:

```
certutil -addstore ca Startup\sfdc-client.cert.cer 2>&1 >> %temp%\AddCerts.out
```

the 2> tells the console to capture the "ERROUT" handle

the &1 binds that output to the STDOUT handle

the >> appends the STDOUT handle to a file